# how to show loading image while ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need to show loading image while ajaz is called....
I did some work on this....
But it was not helpful 
...It is not showing loading image....
And i want to block screen when image is loading...
my ajax is here below...

```
----ajax---

function checkEmail(value_email_mobile) {

                 // before the request, show the GIF
                 //$('#loader').show();
                if (value_email_mobile !== '') {

                     //alert('te');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url_check_user_avail_status, 
                        data: "value_email_mobile="+value_email_mobile,
                        success: function(msg) {

                            //alert(msg);

                            //$('#psid').html("<img src='images/spacer.gif'>");
                              $('#loader').hide();
                            $('#validation').html(msg);


                            //

                            //$('#sid').sSelect({ddMaxHeight: '300px'});

                        },
                        error: function() {
                            //alert('some error has occured...');
                        },
                        start: function() {
                            //alert('ajax has been started...');
                             $("#loader").show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } 

------html--

<div id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="<wait.png" ></div>
```

Comment: Is it because you have a typo in your image name? `<img src="<wait.png" >`

Comment: I think `start` isn't a valid parameter. Just move the `$('#loader').show();` line to just before the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your image tag is invalid `<img src="<wait.png" >` should look like `<img src="wait.png"/>`

As for the loader, $.ajax has an option called beforeSend.  You can use it like so:

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url_check_user_avail_status, 
                    data: "value_email_mobile="+value_email_mobile,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                                    $("#loader").show();
                                },
                    success: function(msg) { // success code here
                         $("#loader").hide();
                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax doesn't have `start` method. Instead you can just show the spinner before calling `$.ajax` and it will work fine.

```
if (value_email_mobile !== '') {

    $("#loader").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url_check_user_avail_status, 
        data: "value_email_mobile="+value_email_mobile,
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#loader").hide();
        },
        error: function() {}
    })

   // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

write this code is working for all ajax request fire on your website.

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#loader").show();
});
```

Then write ajax stop code.

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#loader").hide();
});
```